# I used python and opencv3 to contour the largest image on live stream, it looks my code went wrong, can anyone help me

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

I used python and opencv3 to contour the largest image on live stream, it looks my code went wrong, can anyone help me

```
import cv2,platform
import numpy as np

def larger(x):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(x, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    image = cv2.Canny(gray,35,200)
    (_,cnts,_) = cv2.findContours(image.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
    return cv2.minAreaRect(c)
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
retval, im = capture.read()
y = larger(im)
box = np.int0(cv2.boxPoints(y))
cv2.drawContours(im,[box],-1,(0,255,0),2)
cv2.imshow("Image",im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

i have two problems with this code:

1. is my web cam was on but cant see any video image, getting this error

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Users\Snehith\Desktop\project vision\cnt.py", line 14, in <module>
       y = larger(im)
     File "C:\Users\Snehith\Desktop\project vision\cnt.py", line 8, in larger
       c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
   ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
   ```
2. i want a continuous video stream along with the contour, please explain the mistakes and also solutions in python and opencv

Answer (score 0):

I only had to do two minor changes to your code:

1.) You can check capture.isOpened() in order to see whether a camera is connected.

2.) I have included a while loop so that you continuously pull frames till 'q' is pressed.

```
import cv2,platform
import numpy as np

def larger(x):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(x, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    image = cv2.Canny(gray,35,200)
    (_,cnts,_) = cv2.findContours(image.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
    return cv2.minAreaRect(c)

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if capture.isOpened():
    while(True):
        retval, im = capture.read()
        y = larger(im)
        box = np.int0(cv2.boxPoints(y))
        cv2.drawContours(im,[box],-1,(0,255,0),2)
        cv2.imshow("Image",im)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            capture.release()
            break

else:
    print "No camera detected."


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

You might find the OpenCV Python Tutorial helpful for similar questions, here is a link to the pdf version:
https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/opencv-python-tutroals/latest/opencv-python-tutroals.pdf